# Перенаправление Nginx -> docker container

Tags: nginx, docker

Хочу разместить своё ASP.NET Core приложение на VPS с помощью docker. Если делать это командой
docker run -d -p 80:80/tcp username/containername
То возникает проблема так как 80 порт уже слушает Nginx. Если его остановить, то всё нормально, но тогда не работают phpMyAdmin, RoundCube и прочее. Можно ли как-то настроить nginx чтобы он не выплёвывал дефолтную страничку сгенерированную VestaCP а перенаправлял запрос с 433 и 80 порта VPS на 80 порт контейнера docker(https моя приложуха не поддерживает).

Comment: Можно настроить. Про это каждый первый пример и каждый второй вопрос.

Comment: Просто запускайте докер не на 80 порту и настраиваете проксирование (proxy_pass) в nginx